# Starting MySQL. ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file

Tags: mysql

I have a Centos and discovered my MySQL wouldn't start after it suddenly failed. I have tried all possible research in google to no avail. Here is the log details

```
root@27583 [~]# tail -200 /var/log/mysql.log
18:53:49 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=134217728
read_buffer_size=2097152
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=500
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 2184911 K  bytes    of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x35)[0x7dad25]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x3e1)[0x693c61]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x7ffa00611ca0]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x7ff9ff8112c5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x110)[0x7ff9ff812d70]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x8deb95]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x8b66c9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x8b6c07]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x8a87e7]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x87eae2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x874ef9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x875514]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x876ab1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x8643ba]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x82d2a9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x46)[0x695c66]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x587e7c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0xcf6)[0x58aac6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x5051e3]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x8ad)[0x50829d]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf4)[0x7ff9ff7fe9c4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x4ff119]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
130209 19:53:49 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file  /var/lib/mysql/deepserver.netaviva.net.pid ended
130209 19:58:50 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
130209 19:58:50 [Warning] The syntax '--log-slow-queries' is deprecated and will be    removed in a future release. Please use '--slow-query-log'/'--slow-query-log-file' instead.
130209 19:58:50 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130209 19:58:50 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130209 19:58:50 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130209 19:58:50 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130209 19:58:50 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
130209 19:58:50 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130209 19:58:50 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130209 19:58:50 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
130209 19:58:50  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
130209 19:58:50  InnoDB: Error: page 7 log sequence number 7922893671086
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 6086292560908.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
InnoDB: Error: trying to access page number 939544476 in space 0,
InnoDB: space name ./ibdata1,
InnoDB: which is outside the tablespace bounds.
InnoDB: Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type 10.
InnoDB: If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that
InnoDB: your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have in the
InnoDB: MySQL server.
130209 19:58:50  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139796076951264 in file fil0fil.c  line 4436
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
 InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
```

Please i would greatly appreciate any help to get this working again.

Comment: The most meaningful thing I can see in there (as a layman) is `Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
tablespace but not the InnoDB log files.` is there something to that?

Comment: I'm very new to this. So i can't figure out what this is saying